# ubuntu mate 21.04 USB stick will not automount

Tags: usb, mate, 21.04, automount

A USB 64 gig stick will not automount.  control center "disk" shows the drive as unmounted.  Gpartd shows the drive as having a FAT32 file system.  Does the same thing when formatted to exFAT.  Yes, I checked the card before posting this question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ubuntu mate 21.04 USB stick'? Is it a USB boot drive? In that case, which tool (or manual method) did you use to create it? Or is it a data storage USB stick, that you want to automount in Ubuntu MATE?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear.  I want a USB stick or SD card to automount to a running system when I plug it in like it's supposed to.  It stopped working in the last upgrade to 21.04

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need help from an **experienced user of Ubuntu MATE**, who can help you activate automounting of USB sticks. Sorry, I use other flavours of Ubuntu, so I can't help much. But I start by asking you to run the following command line: `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,MODEL | grep -v '/snap/'` in a wide terminal window and post the result in your original question. Please render it as `code`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I answered my own question.  On a hunch, I reinstalled FUSE and did a reboot.  That resolved the problem.  I loaded the card with music and now it's in my new music player.

Answer (score 3):

Since I got no help here, on a hunch, I reinstalled the FUSE filesystem

`$ sudo apt-get reinstall fuse`

and a reboot seems to have solved the problem.